# Laravel 5.5 multiple controller on single view

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have web pages that have `search form` that need to populate data from database like `category`, there lot of page on my site like `gallery` `blog` `etc`.

every page has the same `search form`.

so I decide to use `@section` and `@extend` for main content and keep the `search form` on my `main layout`.

here my `controller`

```
public function index()
{
    $post = Post::all();

    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('events.show', compact('post', 'category'));
}

public function show($slug)
{
    $post = Post::where('slug',$slug)->first();

    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('events.show', compact('post', 'category'));
}
```

on my code above I need to call `category` list like every `function` also every `controller`

there's a way to make it without `$categories = Category::all();` every `function` also every `controller` ?...

so just call once and work every page.

Comment: try to use `view composers` > `https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers`

Comment: You don't want to retrieve data `Category::all();` in every function, You want to retrieve data once and use it in everywhere without calling again and again, Right ?

Comment: @raff exactly, any solution?

Comment: U can create custom helper for this....

Answer (score 0):

in your `app/AppServiceProvider` **boot()** method , get categories , then it will be available to all blade views , so no need to get and set categories inside each controller's functions .

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use App\Category;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
         View::share('key', 'value');
         Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
         $categories= Category::all();
         View::share('categories',$categories);   
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

in side your any blade view file you can access categories like below:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
<p>{{$category->name}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: simple way why need `Schema::defaultStringLength(191)` ?

Comment: I have just pasted code from my project , so thats why it is